# how to index the option not chosen

Tags: python

The code simulates the choice between two options with a certain probability, which is updated from the CK equation, but this in turn is updated depending on the chosen option.
I would like to know if there's a way to 'index' the not chosen ooption in the second CK equation
Thanks

````
    d=np.zeros((2,2)) 
    choices = np.zeros((T), dtype = int)
    rewards = np.zeros((T), dtype = int)

    CK = [0,0]

    for trial in range(T):
        p0=np.exp(beta_c*CK[0]) / (np.exp(beta_c*CK[0]+beta_c*CK[1]))
        p1=1-p0
        proba=[p0,p1]

        c=np.random.choice(range(K),p=proba)
        r=1 if np.random.rand()<mu[c] else 0

      #Update values
        CK[c] = CK[c] + alpha_c * 1
        CK = (1-alpha_c) * CK  ##How do I make this update with the not chosen option?

        d[c,r]+=1
        choices[trial]=c
        rewards[trial]=r        
      
    return d,choices,rewards```
````

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you only have two options: `list(filter(lambda x: x != chosen_option))[0]`.